# Linq Skip & Take - Why does it build a WHERE clause?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, paging

I´m implementing server side paging and sorting, clearly everyone out there recommends using SKIP and TAKE. 
 I have to wait 13 seconds to get 25 rows, I then looked up why. In SQL I get the following query:

```
 exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t1].[Id], [t1].[Updated], [t1].[Updater], [t1].[ProductId], [t1].[AccountId], [t1].[CountryId], [t1].[CurrencyId], [t1].[Year], [t1].[Storage], [t1].[AuditLog]
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [t0].[Id], [t0].[Updated], [t0].[Updater], [t0].[ProductId], [t0].[AccountId], [t0].[CountryId], [t0].[CurrencyId], [t0].[Year], [t0].[Storage]) AS [ROW_NUMBER], [t0].[Id], [t0].[Updated], [t0].[Updater], [t0].[ProductId], [t0].[AccountId], [t0].[CountryId], [t0].[CurrencyId], [t0].[Year], [t0].[Storage], [t0].[AuditLog]
    FROM [MtrMain].[VCalculationResult] AS [t0]
    ) AS [t1]
WHERE [t1].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN @p0 + 1 AND @p0 + @p1
ORDER BY [t1].[ROW_NUMBER]',N'@p0 int,@p1 int',@p0=5,@p1=15
```

Also the C# code:

```
context.CalculationResults
                        .Select(cre =>CalculationResult>.CopyFrom(cre))
                        .Skip(skip)
                        .Take(take)
                        .ToList();
```

Could you please help me finding an alternative solution?

Comment: How do you think Skip and Take *should* be implemented?

Comment: What are you actually asking?  If you're just curious about the implementation of Skip and Take, what does that have to do with any performance issue you're experiencing?  If you're looking to solve the performance issue, what does the implementation of Skip and Take have to do with that?  What specifically are you looking for here?

Comment: *Could you please help me finding an alternative solution?* Yes: use Entity Framework. EF uses the best paging alternatives of the available SQL Server version.

Comment: if you want to see OFFSET (paging functionality) switch to entity framework 6.1.3

Comment: Your C# LINQ has an error in the `Select`.

Comment: EF is not an alternative in my case, what is the error in the select?

Answer (score 1):

Can you run the query directly against the database and look at the execution plan? Can you compare the time it takes running it in management studio to the application side? To me there isn't anything inherently wrong with that query and you would want to use row_number over in SQL in order to accomplish this most efficiently. The only thing that I could think of just based on the query is indexing. If VCalculationResult is a large table and is not indexed on id then you'd have to do a table scan instead of a seek each time. Also if id is not unique you'd have to look at adding additional columns to cover the query.

You also could gain some performance boost by creating a stored proc so that the query is compiled and doesn't have to be done ad-hoc on the parameters you pass each time. I've done this at times when performance is an issue in entity framework. Often for paged searches of a large dataset like this I'll create a stored proc and run an execute statement in my search function and map the results to the model collection myself. It takes a bit more coding on the application side, but for specific calls such as this it could be worth it.

Comment: I tried in SQL Management Studio, still took more than 10 seconds, I will try with a stored procedure. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your table has an ordered sequential field already in it (is `Id` a numeric field that is sequential?) and you don't care to have a different order, you can use `Where` on that field instead of `Skip`/`Take` to get a page of rows.

If you have an ordered field that isn't sequential, you could run a query once to create an in memory `List` of the ordered field values and their row numbers, saving only every nth value and then again use a `Where` to find the rows that belong on the page, assuming you don't have too many pages to hold in-memory.

Something like

```
var index = context.CalculationResults.AsEnumerable().Select((cr,i) => new { cr.Id, i }).Where(g => g.i % take == 0).Select(g => g.Id).ToList();
```

(Unfortunately, the two argument `Select` doesn't work with LINQ to SQL.)

Then you could use the `index` to get a page:

```
var page = context.CalculationResults.Where(cr => cr.Id >= index[pageNum-1] && (pageNum < index.Count ? index.cr.Id < index[pageNum] : true)).ToList();
```

If you are using T-SQL or something similar that has a `ROW_NUMBER` function, you can execute a SQL query to generate the index server side:

```
var index = context.ExecuteQuery<int>("SELECT ID FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS rn,ID FROM [MtrMain].[VCalculationResult]) AS t1 WHERE (t1.rn-1) % 10 = 0").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I tried different approaches and when I started building the stored procedure, I found the reason for the slow query: I oversaw that one of the fields holds an XML file. Selecting all fields (including one with a binary file) but the XML Log, makes the query perform how I needed it.